# Android ACRA send logs whitout crash

Tags: android, acra, acralyzer

I'm new to ACRA and i have one question : is there a way to send logcat whithout any crash ?

For ex : when the user close the app ... ACRA just send last logs to server

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-for-caught-exceptions-or-for-unexpected-application-state-without-any-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a report at any time using [ErrorReporter.handleException](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-for-caught-exceptions-or-for-unexpected-application-state-without-any-exception) with argument `null` (or an Exception you just created or caught).

However, it is not possible to send only `logcat`, unless ACRA is configured to always do that.